# making a new variable categorized from old strings in R

Tags: r

I am looking to make a new column in a dataframe that looks at another column in a dataframe and categorizes. Here is a problem statement and example to make it more concrete. I have a column in a dataframe that is the Product Number, I want to look at the first 3 characters in the Product Number string and group all terms that have the same 3 characters and call that something like Product 1 and store that in another column called Product, like so:

```
Product_Number          Product
1000100                 Product 1
1000200                 Product 1
1000300                 Product 1
2000200                 Product 2
2000100                 Product 2
2000200                 Product 2
```

Hopefully that is clear, does anybody know of a clever way that this can be accomplished. Pretty much I am trying to reduce my amount of factors from 1200 in the Product_Number column to around 100 factors in the Product column.

Jamey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `substr` to extract the first three characters and then construct a factor from it. As a demo:

```
df$Product <- paste("Product", as.numeric(factor(substr(df$Product_Number, 1, 3))), sep = " ")
```

Which gives:

```
df
#   Product_Number   Product
# 1        1000100 Product 1
# 2        1000200 Product 1
# 3        1000300 Product 1
# 4        2000200 Product 2
# 5        2000100 Product 2
# 6        2000200 Product 2
```

Comment: Thanks that is very helpful and will suffice for my purposes. I knew there was probably a simple way to achieve this. Thanks agian!